# jQuery draggable option disable layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, draggable

I got this code from the net:

```
<div id="draggable">
  <div id = "editable" contenteditable="true"> </div>
</div>

<script>
var draggableDiv = $('#draggable').draggable();

$('#editable', draggableDiv).mousedown(function(ev) {
     draggableDiv.draggable('disable');
}).mouseup(function(ev) {
     draggableDiv.draggable('enable');
});
</script>
```

The code: http://jsfiddle.net/cSMYG/1/

How can I change the default event when I click and hold down the cursor on the text field and then while holding down, hover out of the text field, will make the text field not grey? I know what's causing it but I can't make a workaround.

Comment: Your explanation is VERY bad. Please try to be more clear and specific and not use wordpair "text field" after every two words.

Comment: @user2831723 What's wrong with using "text field" to refer to text fields? If something is unclear, I feel that asking questions to get more details or giving suggestions on how to improve would help more than saying "Your explanation is VERY bad. Please be more clear and specific". That being said, the question *can* use some improvement. Describing what is currently happening, what you want to happen, and what you have tried goes a long way to helping others answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to attach the `mouseup` event handler on an ancestor element. For example:

```
$(document).mouseup(function(ev) {
     draggableDiv.draggable('enable');
});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cSMYG/121/)**

You may also want to keep track of whether it's disabled in a variable, and then check that before enabling it on every `mouseup` event:

```
var isDraggableEnabled = ...
```

Comment: Is it possible for the object not to turn grey when clicking it?

Comment: @Larssen It's not turning grey, but is actually becoming more transparent. I believe this is set by jQuery UI, so you will need to override the styling it has applied: `.ui-state-disabled { opacity: 1; }`